# in R iterating through subsetted data

Tags: r

I am attempting an assignment for courser, so this is homework. I am hoping someone will explain why what I am doing does not work.
I have a data frame called complete_cases and I have to report back how many records there are in specified 'sets' of observations from a much larger 'set'
The data are in the format:

```
              Date sulfate nitrate ID
279 2003-10-06    7.21   0.651  1
285 2003-10-12    5.99   0.428  1
291 2003-10-18    4.68   1.040  1
297 2003-10-24    3.47   0.363  1
303 2003-10-30    2.42   0.507  1
315 2003-11-11    1.43   0.474  1
```

and so on for 332 different sets with the id 1 to 332. I have 'found' the instances in which the record is complete and have to return which set the data are from and how many complete sets of data there are in the specified set( by id)
I am trying to use:

```
for (i in id){
   list <- nrow(complete_cases[i])
   data<-cbind(id = i,  nobs= list)
  }
```

data
If I call the function using one set of data, it appears to work fine:
gives me:

```
      id nobs
[1,]  1  117
```

but trying to apply it to an id <- c(2,4,8,10,12) gives me the error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(complete_cases, i) : undefined columns selected
```

So what I was expecting is that the iteration would return the number of rows for each id in c(2,4,8,10,12) and return the id and the size for each id. Is this any clearer?

Comment: The syntax df[i] selects the ith column so my guess is that you are trying to select a column index that does not exist.

Comment: sorry for being unclear. The function is called as functional(data,id) where id is c(2,4,8,10,12) indicating the subset of data

Comment: I am still a bit confused on how you are indexing specific subsets of a dataframe -- can you provide a bit more of your code please? A toy dataset would be preferable as well

Comment: You should not call a variable "list" as that name is used already by R. Call it "MyList" or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the way you are subsetting the data, in order to specify that the column `ID` should be the one referenced by the iterator value you must be more specific. There a number of ways to do this, here is one:

```
complete_cases[complete_cases$ID == i, ]
```

You also are going to be writing over your vector every time by just using `data <- ...` my personal favorite, which does not require you to specify the dimension of your final set, goes like this:

```
data_summary <- vector("list")
k <- 1
for (i in id){
   current_id_rowcount <- nrow(complete_cases[complete_cases$ID == i, ])
   data_summary[[k]] <-cbind(id = i,  nobs=current_id_rowcount)
   k <- k + 1
}    
final <- do.call(rbind, data_summary)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Previous suggestion, as you said, overwrites, but was still much better than I achieved. So thank you both